# Hebrew word/image HELP for Paintings

Tags: hebrew

I am an artist and have completed five paintings of 5 different Hebrew words for our prayer room.  I don't speak Hebrew, but was told that the images and words were correct, but one was in question and now I am questioning all of them! I just don't know if I have painted them correctly. I may have to repaint my letters! 
I have painted these words just as the letters will be as you see them.....as if you are standing in front of the painting and looking at it....The characters are written just as they appear...below...I tried to do them on your typewriter, but could not read some of them. I would even send pics of the paintings if possible on another less public post if someone can help me! I would deeply appreciate someone looking at this! Thanks, Deborah

Beloved (Dodi)
Yud Dalet Vav Dalet

Covenant Love (Ahava)
Hey Bet hey alph
אהבה

Lovingkindness (Chesed)
Dalet samech Chet

Desire (Teshukah)
Hey Quph Vav shin Tav

Ra'eyah (Lover)
Resh Ayin yod Hey

Answer (score 1):

Beloved (Dodi) דודי

Love (Ahava) אהבה

Lovingkindness (Chesed) חסד

Desire (Teshukah) תשוקה

Companion (Ra'eyah) רֵעַ

Hebrew reads from right to left.

Your first four transliterations read from left to right and the last one reads from  right to left and in my view includes a Hey ה which should not be there.

Comment: According to Google translate, it could be re'a without a hey like you said, which it says is companion, or ra'e with a hey which it says is mate (really the same thing

Comment: According to [this Hebrew dictionary](https://archive.org/details/AComprehensiveEtymologicalDictionaryOfTheHebrewLanguageErnestKlein1987OCR), pages 621 and 622, all of these are legitamate forms. רֵעַ would be a male friend, companion, or associate.  רעה would be a female friend or companion.  רעיה would be female friend, beloved, spouse.

Comment: [Shir HaShirim 2:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3002.htm#2) I'm pretty sure you are mistaken